# In PHP return result or empty array

Tags: php

In javascript I can write something like:

```
var result = Whatever() || [];
```

and if `Whatever()` returns `null` or `undefined`, the `result` variable will contain an empty array.

Is there a similar shortcut in PHP? This will just return false:

```
$result = Whatever() || array();
```

I can use a ternary operator, but since there is a function call, I will need to create an additional variable like so:

```
$whatever = Whatever();
$result = $whatever ? $whatever : array();
```

which seems ugly and not very readable. Is there a better pattern?

Comment: `return Whatever() ? Whatever() : [];` or `return Whatever() ? Whatever() : array()` - as you said, those are your best bets - it's called a Ternary Operator or shortcutted : http://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop reading old php posts on internet. You can easily do

```
$result = Whatever() ?: array();
```

**PHP 5.3+**

And nope, `Whatever()` won't be called twice.

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/391006)**